# Dynamically generate a webpage in GWT

Tags: javascript, web-applications, gwt, mathjax

I have a unique challenge that I'm not sure how to approach:
I need to manufacture a new HTML page from scratch, one that contains a script tag and a paragraph tag with some words in it. Very simple! Once the page is built, I just need to open it in a new tab. As long as a I can call the script tag from within it, a popup is fine too. Basically, I am going to use a library called MathJax which will typeset all the elements on the html page it loads on.

I'm not even sure what this functionality is formally called, or if it's even possible in GWT! Any guidance at all would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use GWT for it. Just write simple servlet that will spit out html with required script tags to load GWT and do whatever else you need and you are done.

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler GWT based solution, but for now I'll try this.